# Finding hard and soft open file limits from within jvm in linux (ulimit -n and ulimit -Hn)

Tags: java, linux, groovy, jvm, ulimit

I have a problem where I need to find out the hard and soft open file limits for the process in linux from within a java/groovy program. When I execute ulimit from the terminal it gives separate values for hard and soft open file limits.

```
$ ulimit -n
1024
$ ulimit -Hn
4096
```

But, if I execute it in groovy, it ignores the soft limit and always returns hard limit value.

```
groovy> ['bash', '-c', 'ulimit -n'].execute().text  
Result: 4096

groovy> ['bash', '-c', 'ulimit -Hn'].execute().text 
Result: 4096
```

Please let me know if I am missing something. I have used ubuntu 12.04, Groovy Version: 1.8.4 JVM: 1.6.0_29 for this execution.

**Update**:
I tried the same thing in Java.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class LinuxInteractor {
    public static int executeCommand(String command, boolean waitForResponse, OutputHandler handler) {
        int shellExitStatus = -1;
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", command);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            Process shell = pb.start();

            if (waitForResponse) {

                // To capture output from the shell
                InputStream shellIn = shell.getInputStream();

                // Wait for the shell to finish and get the return code
                shellExitStatus = shell.waitFor();

                convertStreamToStr(shellIn, handler);
                shellIn.close();
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Error occured while executing Linux command. Error Description: "
                            + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Error occured while executing Linux command. Error Description: "
                            + e.getMessage());
        }
        return shellExitStatus;
    }

    public static String convertStreamToStr(InputStream is, OutputHandler handler) throws IOException {

        if (is != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                        "UTF-8"));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    String output = new String(buffer, 0, n);
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);

                    if(handler != null)
                        handler.execute(output);
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public abstract static class OutputHandler {
        public abstract void execute(String str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OutputHandler handler = new OutputHandler() {
            @Override
            public void execute(String str) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        };

        System.out.print("ulimit -n : ");
        LinuxInteractor.executeCommand("ulimit -n", true, handler);
        System.out.print("ulimit -Hn : ");
        LinuxInteractor.executeCommand("ulimit -Hn", true, handler);
    }

}
```

Output for this program:

```
$ java LinuxInteractor 
ulimit -n : 4096

ulimit -Hn : 4096
```

Why is the behavior same in Java. Is java setting ulimit by any chance.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Groovy is setting this limit to maximum in it's start-up scripts.

In `startGroovy:160`:

```
# Increase the maximum file descriptors if we can.
if [ "$cygwin" = "false" -a "$darwin" = "false" ] ; then
    MAX_FD_LIMIT=`ulimit -H -n`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        if [ "$MAX_FD" = "maximum" -o "$MAX_FD" = "max" ] ; then
            MAX_FD="$MAX_FD_LIMIT"
        fi
        ulimit -n $MAX_FD
        if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
            warn "Could not set maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD"
        fi
    else
        warn "Could not query businessSystem maximum file 
              descriptor limit: $MAX_FD_LIMIT"
    fi
fi
```

---

It turns out jvm is setting this limit by itself. I'm not sure why groovy is changing it too. Try:

```
java -XX:-MaxFDLimit LinuxInteractor
```

It will disable this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Banthar. I have updated my question with execution in java, where I am finding a similar behavior.