# Not getting any output after calling C executable file from Java code

Tags: java, c, process, runtime.exec

I am trying to execute the C code from Java code which is already compiled and executed, but, I am not getting any output from the executable file. Can anyone help me to complete this task?

Code is as follows.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Process processCompile = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("e:/Sample.exe");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C executables are no different from other executables, at least from the point of view of process execution. As @JunedAhsan points out, the problem is that you have to read the executable's output yourself (and either show it or do something with it).

Comment: Go through the Java World article linked from the [`exec` info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info), implement **all** the recommendations, then use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the `Process`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(processCompile .getInputStream()));


// read the output from the command
System.out.println("EXE OUTPUT");
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Make sure that your C process is actually returning something to the console. Above code is to capture a process output provided there is some output.

Comment: @Sankar you can accept the answer so that others can be benefited with it.

Answer (score 0):

This method would work only if you run the java program with admin privileges.

If you have privileges, then can you try running your process under "cmd" shell (Which is forked by your java process). An implementation do so this is done here "LinuxInteractor" ( But is in linux). Just minor change needed to port to Windows version.

[Finding hard and soft open file limits from within jvm in linux (ulimit -n and ulimit -Hn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877271/finding-hard-and-soft-open-file-limits-from-within-jvm-in-linux-ulimit-n-and-u)

Comment: The C program (Sample.exe)is executing from Java Code, I have checked in the task manager, but the problem is that i am not getting any console (output) from the C Program